# Rake routes not showing the route, but it exists when hardcoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth

I'm using Devise and Omniauth for my login process. For some reason, I can access the route "users/auth/facebook" or "users/auth/twitter" just fine. But they don't show up when I do rake routes, so I have no idea what the helper method to get these paths is (e.g. something_something_path). Can someone help me out?

I can't show all of my routes, but I can say that the only route that matches "/users/auth/..." that's showing up is this one (from rake routes):

```
 user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)    {:action=>/(?!)/, :controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

BTW, when I say I "can access the route just fine", I mean this works (redirects me correctly to facebook or twitter):

```
<%= link_to "Connect", "users/auth/facebook" %>
```

Also, the routes should be the default Devise omniauth routes for the user model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to why this doesn't show up in `rake routes`, first note how the task is implemented. It is part of [railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake), and it gets the routes to show [as such](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake#L4):

```
Rails.application.routes.routes
```

So we can see that it is asking the `Rails.application` for its routes.

---

Next note that the [Omniauth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/) "is a flexible authentication system utilizing Rack middleware".

Because it uses Rack middleware it does not 'know' anything about the `Rails.application` used by `rake routes`, and so its routes don't appear in that task.

You can get a good introduction to Rack middleware in [this Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware).

---

Delving a little deeper we can see from `rake middleware` that `OmniAuth::Builder` appears before your rails app in the stack. So how does it handle the `auth/twitter` route?

It does so by checking for a `request_path` in its `call`, you can see the check [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/1.0-beta/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L41), and you can see how the `request_path` is built [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/1.0-beta/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L138) (`path_prefix` is `auth` by default, and `name` in your case is `twitter`.

When using Omniauth with Devise, the `path_prefix` is set automatically, as noted [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.5/lib/devise/omniauth.rb#L13).

Comment: Excellent answer, and awesome haircut! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why they dont show up on rake routes, I am not sure. But if you wanna know their alias you can find them in here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

From their docs:

> Currently, Devise only allows you to make one model omniauthable.
>   After making a model named User omniauthable and if "devise_for
>   :users" was already added to your config/routes.rb, Devise will create
>   the following url methods:
>
> user_omniauth_authorize_path(provider)
>   user_omniauth_callback_path(provider)

So if you have `devise_for :model` in your routes you should see that url method.

Example:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

Also if you take a look at the implementation of devise, you can see that the URL helpers are there:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/omniauth/url_helpers.rb

Comment: Yes.. tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work either. Undefined method error. :(

Comment: which version of omniauth r u using? 1.0 ?

Comment: I just added a piece from the docs. it just work if u have devise_for in your routes. if it still doesnt work, i would say that u could file a ticket..